# Quick way to check if a NodeList has more than one node?

Tags: javascript

How can I quickly check if a NodeList (derived from a parent) contains more than one node?

E.g if I have some divs:

```
<div class="parent">
    <div></div>
    <div></div>
    <div><span></span></div>
</div>
```

I want to check if "parent" contains more than one div or not like this:

```
var parentDiv = document.querySelector(".parent");

var children = parentDiv.getElementsByTagName("div");

if (children > 1) {
    alert("more than 1 child");
}
else {
     alert("less than 1 child");
}

console.log(children);
```

However, this doesn't work. Is there a quick way of doing simply? Maybe some sort of array prototype or something?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use the `.length` property:

```
if (children.length > 1) {
    alert("more than 1 child");
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try `children.length`. [NodeLists](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/API/NodeList) have that property as well.